# Need to convert C# to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I have some C# source code that I got off the Internet and I want it in VB.NET. How would you convert it because I don't know C#.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756590/good-way-to-convert-vb-net-to-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found multiple translators after performing a simple search, but [this one looks kind of cool](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/).  No installation necessary!... though I have never used it.

Comment: Yes it's good. muckdog12, if you have a problem with some part of the code that isn't translated correctly, just post it here.

Comment: This is pretty cool (i'd never have an application for it, but cool nonetheless!)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is compiling it to, dragging the assembly to Reflector and then decompiling it to VB.NET

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, you can have multiple source languages in the same project.  They just have to be in different files.  You should be able to call the c# class from a vb.net class without any major problems.  This may not be the prettiest option, but it might work for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a VB project in the same solution as a C# project, and use classes from either from the other, but you can't have both VB and C# source files compiled in the same project.